# Mutable variable available to all classes?

Tags: c#, variables, global, mutable

I'm developing a program in C# and need a mutable variable that is available to all classes in my program.

For example, I want to set it to a default value, say `false`, when the program starts, then be able to change it to `true` later when an action occurs.  The `true` value then needs to be conveyed when other classes read it.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm new to C# - my problem was I couldn't figure out how to access the static variable I declared in the `Program` class.  Turns out it was as simple at `Program.myVar`.  Duh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a static?:

```
public static class MyProps
{
    public static bool MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

In your code:

```
MyProps.MyProp = true;
```

No initialisation necessary because booleans always initialise to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Three options:

- Make it an instance variable of a particular type, and make sure every class has access to the same instance
- Make it a static variable of a particular type
- Somewhere in between: make it an instance variable in a [singleton type](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Personally I would favour the first approach in conjuction with dependency injection - but think about which classes *really* need to know about this. Is it really *every* class in your program?

Global state (via static variables) and singletons make code harder to test in general.

Also, I would definitely make it a private variable and have a property to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a static member in a class somewhere.

```
class MyClass {
  static bool ms_MyStatic = false;
}
```

...you can reference this as MyClass.ms_MyStatic wherever you like.