# .net access local variable inside of class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am new to C# and the .Net framework and struggling to understand how to do something. Do I lean on Inheritance for something like this?

When the variable `allDim` is true, I want all class instances to return 0 for their `dimPercent.`

```
public class Program
{
    //if this is true, all rooms should return 0
    public bool allDim = false;
    public class Room
    {
        //0 is lights out. 100 is as bright as possible
        public Room(int dimPercent)
        {
            DimPercent = dimPercent;
        }

        private int dimPercent;
        public int DimPercent
        {
            get
            {
                if (Program.allDim)
                {
                    //if allDim is true, all lights should be dimmed to 0 percent
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return dimPercent;
                }
            }

            set
            {
                dimPercent = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Room livingRoom = new Room(80);
        Room kitchen = new Room(85);
        Room bedroom = new Room(65);
        allDim = true;
        // This should return 0 since allDim was set to true
        Console.WriteLine(kitchen.DimPercent);
    }
}
```

Creating a base class that holds `allDim` and allowing the Room class to be derived from this new base class did not feel right to me since `allDim` is technically not a property of each class instance. Apologies if I butchered some of the terminology.

Comment: You should set allDim is static like this: public static bool allDim  = false;

Comment: You should not make public fields. Make it a property at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mutable variable available to all classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088693/mutable-variable-available-to-all-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your boolean into a Static Member of the class.

```
public static bool allDim = false;
```

Comment: public fields is a bad practice, better use properties

Comment: It's bad because you're exposing the internal state of your object, and you don't have any control over how that state is changed. With getters and setters, you can at least inspect the data and modify it if necessary, so your object's internal state remains consistent (and valid). From here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/161310/114942

Comment: Point taken. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you make `allDim` into a private static field then you would easily achieve what you want. However from the point of responsibility, you should ask yourself if any of the room instances should be able to affect other rooms?

```
public class Room
{
    private static bool allDim = false;
    // I am not sure if we should make this into a static method
    public void SetAllDim(bool isAllDim){
        allDim = isAllDim;
    }
...
}
```